# Basic Python query

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone help me on the below syntax?

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` `df`and want to perform :

```
if (df['Contract_Stage'] == "Stage 1"):
  df['DaysToContractEnd'].fillna(600, inplace=True)
elif(df['Contract_Stage']=="Stage 2"):
  df['DaysToContractEnd'].fillna(350, inplace=True)
elif(df['Contract_Stage']=="Stage 3"):
  df['DaysToContractEnd'].fillna(150, inplace=True)
elif(df['Contract_Stage']=="Stage 4"):
  df['DaysToContractEnd'].fillna(-30, inplace=True)
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-27-140b902fd3f8>", line 1, in <module>
if (df['Contract_Stage'] == "Stage 1"):

File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 892, in __nonzero__
.format(self.__class__.__name__))

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: The issue is not syntax (although the indentation is wrong in what you have posted; I assume it is correct in the real code). The error message tells you what to do - have you tried what it suggests?

Comment: Yes the indentation is correct in real code. But I'm very new to python. Trying to understand the error but not able to get it. Can you please help me on this one?

Comment: I fixed the indentation.

Comment: Unrelated, but you could make this code much shorter using a `dict` like `{"Stage 1": 600, "Stage 2": 350, ...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df['Contract_Stage'] == "Stage 1"` will output a vector of `True` or `False`, its shape is (df.shape[0], 1).

So when you do `if df['Contract_Stage'] == "Stage 1"` it is impossible to evaluate it as `True` or `False`

What you can do is :

```
stage1 = df.loc[df['Contract_Stage'] == "Stage 1",'DaysToContractEnd']
stage1.fillna(600, inplace=True)
df.loc[df['Contract_Stage'] == "Stage 1",'DaysToContractEnd'] = stage1
```

This means :

- you get column `'DaysToContractEnd'` for all lines where the condition `df['Contract_Stage'] == "Stage 1"`is `True` and assign it to a temp variable `stage1`.
- In `stage1` you fill na with `600`.
- You replace column `'DaysToContractEnd'` for all lines  where the
  condition `df['Contract_Stage'] == "Stage 1"`is `True` by `stage1`.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:3191: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._update_inplace(new_data)